# A simple program to print full names

Tags: python

I have written this code but when entering any name even not in the first tuple it prints lst[0] which is john matias fredick

```
first = ("John", "Jonathan", "Omar")
second = ("Matias", "Abdo", "Henedy",)
third = ("Fredick", "Abo-elm3ati", "Elmasry")
full = zip(first, second, third)
lst = []
for i in full:
    lst.append((' '.join(str(z) for z in i)))
x = input("Enter your first name: ")

if x.lower() or x.upper() or x.capitalize() == "John":
    print(f"Your full name is {lst[0]}")
elif x.lower() or x.upper() or x.capitalize() == "Jonathan":
    print(f"Your full name is {lst[1]}")
elif x.lower() or x.upper() or x.capitalize() == "Omar":
    print(f"Your full name is {lst[2]}")
else:
    print("We don't know your full name :(")
```

Comment: You need to generalise your question so it's not just asking for the answer to a very narrow problem. That being said try printing put the full variable before hand to make sure its been assembled correctly, then i each time in the loop and then the lst variable. I imagine somewhere your losing the data

Answer (score 2):

When you are using the `lower()` method by itself in an `if` condition, Python takes the Boolean value of that string which is only `False` if the string is empty.

I'm assuming this is what you are looking for:

```
first = ("John", "Jonathan", "Omar")
second = ("Matias", "Abdo", "Henedy",)
third = ("Fredick", "Abo-elm3ati", "Elmasry")
full = zip(first, second, third)
lst = []
for i in full:
    lst.append((' '.join(str(z) for z in i)))
x = input("Enter your first name: ")

if x.lower() == "john" or x.upper() == "JOHN" or x.capitalize() == "John":
    print(f"Your full name is {lst[0]}")
elif x.lower() == "jonathon" or x.upper() == "JONATHON" or x.capitalize() == "Jonathan":
    print(f"Your full name is {lst[1]}")
elif x.lower() == "omar" or x.upper() == "OMAR" or x.capitalize() == "Omar":
    print(f"Your full name is {lst[2]}")
else:
    print("We don't know your full name :(")
```

---

I would like to note that you don't need those three conditions for each if statement. Only one of the first two (`lower()` or `upper()`) is sufficient enough to obtain the desired results.

So, instead of:

```
if x.lower() == "john" or x.upper() == "JOHN" or x.capitalize() == "John":
    print(f"Your full name is {lst[0]}")
```

You could simplify to:

```
if x.lower() == "john":
    print(f"Your full name is {lst[0]}")
```

Answer (score 1):

For future reference, this code can more efficiently be rewritten using a dictionary:

```
first = ("John", "Jonathan", "Omar")
second = ("Matias", "Abdo", "Henedy",)
third = ("Fredick", "Abo-elm3ati", "Elmasry")

names = dict(zip(map(str.lower, first), zip(first, second, third)))
x = input("Enter your first name: ").lower()
if x in names:
    print(f"Your full name is {' '.join(names[x])}")
else:
    print("We don't know your full name :(")
```

Comment: I don't understand what dict and map does here.

Comment: @IbrahimEmbaby map applies a function onto every element into the list. he then zips first, second, and third, and then zips it again so it looks like this: `names = dict( ("john", ("John", "Matias", "Fredrick")), ("jonathan", ("Jonathan", "Abdo", "Abo-elm3ati")), ("omar", ("Omar", "Henedy", "Elmasry")) )`

Comment: a dictionary is basically used to index into an element using a hashable object, in this case he is using a string to index into the required tuple basically looking like this:
names = {"john": ("John", "Matias", "Fredrick"),
               "jonathan": ("Jonathan", "Abdo", "Abo-elm3ati"),
               "omar": ("Omar", "Henedy", "Elmasry")
}

Comment: @IbrahimEmbaby allowing him to index into an element using the key such as `"john"`, so he can get the values `("John", "Matias", "Fredrick")` from doing `names['john']`

Answer (score 0):

I hope I have understood your requirements fully.  Not sure if this helps... I thought:

1. using a loop and then capitalise the input (assuming your names in lst will always be capitalised.. perhaps, some names might not... and you need to cater for it)
2. extract the first name from the list
3. compare them

The code below is not so pythonic.  The above dictionary method is a much better implementation of your requirements.

---

```
first = ("John", "Jonathan", "Omar")
second = ("Matias", "Abdo", "Henedy",)
third = ("Fredick", "Abo-elm3ati", "Elmasry")
full = zip(first, second, third)
lst = []
for i in full:
    lst.append((' '.join(str(z) for z in i)))
    
x = input("Enter your first name: ")

found = False
    
for i in lst:
    if x.capitalize() == i.split()[0]:
        print(f"Your full name is {i}")
        found = True
        break
        
if not found:
    print("We don't know your full name :(")
```